# Generic web repository connector in Mylyn 3.8.1 for Eclipse 4.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, redmine, mylyn, redmine-plugins

I am new to Mylyn and I wanted to integrate it with Redmine 2.0. I found this [Mylyn plugin for Redmine 2.0](http://danmunn.github.com/redmine_mylyn_connector/). But when I installed Mylyn 3.8.1 ([latest at the moment](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/)), I can't find "generic web repository connector" to create the link with Redmine.

What is the version of Mylyn that's compatiple with Eclipes 4.2 and has "generic web repository connector"?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I am currently facing the same problem, I entered my values but just don't see any results but also no error messages

Answer (score 0):

The 'Generic Web repository connector' is a incubator project. You will find using this [0] link as repository url. After you installed it you can follow instructions at [1]

- [0] http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.8
- [1] http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn

Comment: I was thinking that incubator version is not compatible with Eclipse 4.2. Anyway, I will test that and let you know.